# Any way I could make this more efficient?

Tags: python, coding-efficiency

I was wondering if there was a way to make this code more efficient? Just stating that I'm kinda new to python and programming as a whole. Any tips would be great. Thanks is advance.

Here is where I got the task from: http://www.101computing.net/how-old-is-your-cat/

The program just transfers the cats age into human years form.

```
convertedAge = 0
stage = 0

question = input("Is you cat under 1 year old?.. Y/N")

if ((question.lower() == "y") or (question.lower() == "yes")):
  ageOfCat = int(input("How old is your cat (in months)?")) #cat < 1 year old
  if 1 <= ageOfCat <= 2:
    convertedAge = "9 to 10 months"
  elif ageOfCat == 3:
    convertedAge = "2 to 3 years"
  elif ageOfCat == 4:
    convertedAge = "5 to 6 years"
  elif ageOfCat == 5:
    convertedAge = "8 to 9 years"
  elif ageOfCat == 6:
    convertedAge = "10 years"
  elif 7 <= ageOfCat <= 8:
    convertedAge = "13 years"
  elif 8 <= ageOfCat <= 11:
    convertedAge = "14 years"
  print("In human years your cat is the equivalent of " + str(convertedAge) + " old.")
else:
  ageOfCat = int(input("How old is your cat (in years)?")) #cat > 1 year old
  if ageOfCat == 1:
    convertedAge = 15
  elif ageOfCat == 2:
    convertedAge = 15 + 9
  else:
    convertedAge = 15 + 9 + ((ageOfCat-2) * 4)
  print("In human years your cat is the equivalent of " + str(convertedAge) + " years old.")
```

Comment: You should consider case input "answer" is not Y or N,  "ageOfCat" is not integer.

Comment: To be fair, the question was about efficiency though, not handling edge cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well for a start, you could try using a dictionary to eliminate all those if/else blocks:

```
convertedAges = {
    1: "9 to 10 months",
    2: "9 to 10 months",
    3: "2 to 3 years", # and so on
}
```

Then use the dictionary:

```
convertedAge = convertedAges[ageOfCat]
```

Honestly, you should focus on readability, especially if you're just starting out. Like your first `if` could just be

```
if question.lower() in "yes": # "y" is in "yes", so is "yes" (a string is a substring of itself)
```

If you start seeing yourself repeat the same (or very similar) lines over and over again, stop and think about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Alright thanks. I haven't seen a dictionary before, something to research I guess :D

Comment: No worries, good luck! It's a really fun language, and great for beginners!

Comment: Just looked at your edit. That's great, honestly thought you had to do it the way I did it. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `list` instead of that `if` structure:

```
if ((question.lower() == "y") or (question.lower() == "yes")):
    ageOfCat = int(input("How old is your cat (in months)?")) #cat < 1 year old
    ages = [None,
            '9 to 10 months',
            '9 to 10 months',
            '2 to 3 years',
            '5 to 6 years',
            '8 to 9 years',
            '10 years',
            '13 years',
            '13 years',
            '14 years',
            '14 years',
            '14 years']
    convertedAge = ages[ageOfCat]
```

And then you can send multiple arguments to `print()` instead of concatenating (and you don't need to cast strings as strings):

```
print("In human years your cat is the equivalent of", convertedAge, "old.")
```

And you can add to the `convertedAge` for older cats:

```
else:
    ageOfCat = int(input("How old is your cat (in years)?")) #cat > 1 year old
    convertedAge = 15
    if ageOfCat > 1:
        convertedAge += 9
    if ageOfCat > 2:
        convertedAge += (ageOfCat-2) * 4
print("In human years your cat is the equivalent of", convertedAge, "years old.")
```

Comment: ah, using a list didn't even occur to me, but I guess it works since ages are all integers, nice one!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So which would be better to use: a dictionary or list, in this case?

Comment: In this case a list would probably be better, as long as your ages are always integers. He's using list indices to look up the values. `[1, 2, 3][0]` would give you 1 (because 1 is the 0th element), 1 would give you 2, and so on. However if you start going into float ages (1.5), etc. you'd probably need to rethink this approach. Dictionary allows you to look up a key, `{1:2}[1]` would give you 2.